# Add new libraries to PATH in node

Tags: node.js, path, ffmpeg

Im trying to use 'node-fluent-ffmpeg' to get the first frame of a video. I added 'ffmpeg' to my node-modules because it was a prerequisite for 'node-fluent-ffmpeg,' however, in my logs it says "cant find ffmpeg."  I dont understand the second paragraph it the 'node-fluent-ffmpeg' documentation where it talks about this.  What are they referring to by PATH and how do i properly connect these two libraries?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you type a command like `dir` or `ls`, your system looks in a set of configured directories for that binary. `PATH` refers to the variable that holds the list of directories.

If the `ffmpeg` binary is not in a directory on your shells `PATH`, then you have to set the path explicitly when you run `node`. This is done with the `FFMPEG_PATH` and `FFPROBE_PATH` environment variables.

You check if the binaries are on your path with `which`.

```
$ which ffmpeg
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
$ which ffprobe
/usr/local/bin/ffprobe
```

If `which` doesn't return a path or your app is running under a different shell environment (like a service would), you can set those module variables specifically when running `node`.

```
FFMPEG_PATH=/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg \
FFPROBE_PATH=/usr/local/bin/ffprobe \
node whatever.js
```

In your case it will be the full path to the `node_modules` directory you put the `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` binaries in.

Comment: So i would just put FFMPEG_PATH = "/node_modules/ffmpeg" ?

Comment: Leading with a `/` would mean `node_modules` is in the directory root.  It's probably some other directory like `/home/you/project/node_modules/ffmpeg`? You could use `./node_modules/ffmpeg` for a relative path, if you always run `node` from your project directory.